# Silence just the directory bit in batch file command

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file I run through the comand prompt. I like to read each command as it's run, however the directory the file sits in is written first. So my command prompt looks like this:

```
C:\really long directory name where my batch file is stored at the moment>mybatchfile arg1 arg2

C:\really long directory name where my batch file is stored at the moment>first command in my batch file
first command output

C:\really long directory name where my batch file is stored at the moment>next command
next command output
```

What I would like to see is the following:

```
C:\really long directory name where my batch file is stored at the moment>mybatchfile arg1 arg2

first command in my batch file
first command output

next command
next command output
```

Is there a command to silence the directory like this?

Comment: Use `@echo off` as the first line of your batch file.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `prompt`? type `prompt $N$G` into command prompt, then you'll see `C>` rather than `C:\really long directory name...>`; to restore the previous default setting, type `prompt $P$G`; see also `prompt /?` for help...

Comment: ...ah, and `prompt $H` makes it appear empty...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name echo doesn't do what I want, as it hides the actual command as well, which I want to see.

Comment: @aschipfl prompt $H is spot on. Exactly the result I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the prompt text, the `prompt` command is the tool you are looking for.

The default prompt text is the current directory path followed by a greater-than sign, referring to your example:

> ```
> C:\really long directory name where my batch file is stored at the moment>
> ```

If you type `prompt drive $N$G` in a command prompt window, the prompt text will change like this:

> ```
> drive C>
> ```

To let the prompt text appear empty, type `prompt $H`, which actually defines a single backspace character as the prompt text.

To restore the default prompt text, type `prompt $P$G` or just `prompt` without arguments.
Type `prompt /?` to see all possible options.

Comment: to return to the system default prompt, you can just use `prompt` without parameters.